# How to dump XML in KissXML

Tags: dump, kissxml

I used KissXML in my project, now I wanna dump XML info for trace like Zend_Debug::dump(XXX) in php.

But I failed to find API support in KissXML.

Any Idea? or I have to implement by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `description` message, or event better, `[xml XMLStringWithOptions:DDXMLNodePrettyPrint]`